# Not getting proper output!! Can anyone explain, what is wrong?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
class parent
{
 public:
 string parnt_name;
 int age;
};
class child:public parent
{
 public:
 string chld_name;
 int age_child;
 child()
 {
    cout<<"Name of child"<<chld_name<<" and age is "<<age<<" his/her parent name is"<<parent::parnt_name<<"and age of parent is "<<parent::age<<endl;
 }
};
int main()
{
  child c1;
  c1.parnt_name="bill";
  c1.age=45;
  c1.age_child=20;
  c1.chld_name="emily";
  return 0;
}
```

Output of the code is

> Name of child and age is 1975241920 his/her parent name is and age of parent is 1975241920

I am learning inheritance and I tried writing a code the upper one but it is not showing proper output. I cannot configure out what's the problem in the code?

Comment: do you know which line in your code calls the constructor?

Comment: What did you expect to happen and why? You print everything in the constructor before you set any values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object constructors are called upon its creation. Meaning that the `child` class's constructor is called in this line: `child c1;`. Now at this line, does it have any data? Since your not initializing the internal variables (the two integers) it will most often contain garbage values. This is why you get an output like that.

To perform what you need, you can either initialize the class by passing those information as arguments,

```cpp
class parent
{
 public:
 parent(string name, int age) : parent_name(name), age(age) {}
 string parnt_name;
 int age;
};

class child : public parent
{
 public:
 string chld_name;
 int age_child;
 child(string parent_name, int parent_age, string child_name, int child_age)
    : parent(parent_name, parent_age), child_name(child_name), age(child_age)
 {
    cout<<"Name of child"<<chld_name<<" and age is "<<age<<" his/her parent name is"<<parent::parnt_name<<"and age of parent is "<<parent::age<<endl;
 }
};

// Now in the main function
int main()
{
  child c1("bill", 45, "emily", 20);
  return 0;
}
```

Or else have another function to print the data.

```cpp
class child:public parent
{
 public:
 string chld_name;
 int age_child;
 child()
 {
 }

 void print_data()
 {
    cout<<"Name of child"<<chld_name<<" and age is "<<age<<" his/her parent name is"<<parent::parnt_name<<"and age of parent is "<<parent::age<<endl;
 }
};

int main()
{
  child c1;
  c1.parnt_name="bill";
  c1.age=45;
  c1.age_child=20;
  c1.chld_name="emily";

  c1.print_data();
  return 0;
}
```

Note: Always initialize data before using them. It might cause you havoc later on.